# Drive XTAL input with logic signal

Tags: oscillator, clock

I'd like to drive the XTAL input to a chip with a logic signal (3V3, 32kHz square) instead of using a real crystal. In general, is this okay, or does the signal need to be filtered/attenuated? At the electrical level, are there any particular things that need to be considered?

(In particular, the chip whose XTAL input I'd like to drive is a Bosch BNO055.)

Comment: You didn't provide a link to the BNO055 datasheet. Have you been able to inspect the internals of the XTAL input?

Comment: I could not find the information in the [Datasheet](https://ae-bst.resource.bosch.com/media/_tech/media/datasheets/BST_BNO055_DS000_14.pdf). I was hoping for a generalized answer relevant also for other people with other chips, but it could be that there is no general answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is now almost three weeks old, but I think I can provide some useful information. The BNO055 XIN32 can probably be driven by a logic signal, with details discussed below.

When this was originally posted, I had asked Bosch if the BNO055 XIN32 could be driven by a clock signal using VDDIO voltage levels. Bosch answered that yes, the XIN32 input can be driven that way, with XOUT32 left floating. I have edited this answer correspondingly.

The remainder of this answer analyzes the situation, and the system implications.

Bosch offers the BMF055, a 'Custom programmable 9-axis motion sensor', in the same package as the BNO055. The BMF055 has the same sensor characteristics (compare pages 2 and 3 of the two datasheets), but is programmable. I make the assumption that the BNO055 is a BMF055 with sensor fusion programming factory-supplied by Bosch. The BMF055 datasheet provides more information.

Section 9.1 of the BMF055 datasheet states that the embedded processor is an Atmel (now Microchip) SAM D20. The pin description table further shows specifically that pin 26 (BNO055 XOUT32) is SAM D20 'PA01', also 'optional 32kHz crystal output', and pin 25 (BNO055 XIN32) is SAM D20 'PA00', also 'optional 32kHz crystal input'. This seems pretty clear, the BNO055 presumably has an embedded SAM D20 connected to XIN32 and XOUT32.

The Atmel SAM D20 datasheet (http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-42129-sam-d20_datasheet.pdf) provides details regarding XIN32. Conveniently, Bosch has used the Atmel SAM D20 nomenclature, you will find details of XIN32 and XOUT32 in the Atmel SAM D20 datasheet.

There are some system issues to deal with.

First, as to voltage levels, the SAM D20 datasheet section 8.1 shows that the external oscillator pins are in the VDDANA (analog) voltage domain, not the VDDIO (digital) voltage domain. The SAM D20 datasheet section 8.2.1 states that these voltages must be the same, unlike some other microcontrollers.

The Atmel SAM D20 supports an external clock connected to XIN32 (datasheet section 17.2). There is more detail in section 17.6.3: the SAM D20 has separate modes for XIN32 as a clock input and XIN32/XOUT32 supporting an external crystal. Presumably the Bosch firmware in the BNO055 sets the mode to external crystal rather than external clock. This has consequences:

1. The SAM D20 datasheet section 17.6.3 explicitly states that the 32kHz external oscillator (XOSC32K) external output (enabled by 'EN32K') is usable only when an external crystal is supplied, not when an external clock is supplied. The SAM D20 datasheet does not describe this external output in more detail, so I am not certain what this external output is, and how it would be affected by connecting an external clock while the oscillator mode is set to crystal.
2. The SAM D20 will drive the XOUT32 pin, because it expects an external crystal. This may or may not be a problem for you. The SAM D20 has an automatic gain control for XOUT32/XIN32, hopefully this will not cause any problems. Presumably the clock input levels will drive the AGC to its lowest gain.
3. The SAM D20 has a programmable startup delay for the 32.768kHz crystal. The SAM D20 datasheet table 40-25 specifies a maximum startup time of 30k cycles (slightly less than 1 second), so presumably Bosch selected a startup delay time on the order of 1 second. Your clock source must be active within the startup delay after the BNO055 is powered on.
4. Notice that a reset signal is not enough to reset the SAM D20 clock system, a power-on reset is required (SAM D20 datasheet section 14.8). So, if your 32kHz clock source can be reset during operation, you may have to control the power to the BNO055 in order to force it through a power-on reset when the clock source resets.

For the PCB I am designing, I decided to leave the BNO055 with its own 32.768kHz crystal instead of driving XIN32 with the 32.768kHz signal already available on the board.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: That's excellent work. (I saw the 'Login In'/'Digital Pin' problem, before I wrote and asked if there was a general answer; well spotted on the BMF055, and well analyzed.) _Please keep us informed if you get an answer from Bosch._ FWIW my reading of 17.6.3 is that the 'Crystal Oscillator Enable' bit will switch XOUT32 for GPIO but will not affect the charactaristics of XIN32; but answer from Bosch or Atmel would be better. By the way, [HERE](https://www.digikey.de/en/articles/techzone/2016/dec/get-on-the-fast-path-to-sensor-fusion-design) is some useful info on the BMF055.

Comment: Captain Normal: Bosch provided a response, and I have edited the answer correspondingly.

Comment: Excellent. Re your point 3: The BNO055 after reset has its SYS_TRIGGER:CLK_SEL as 0 (internal clock), so the controlling uP can wait til the 32kHz clock is active before switching the BNO055 to external clock. I presume therefore (re your point 4) that a reset will be enough, without controlling the power to the BNO055 - unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Thank you for the clever suggestion regarding the 32kHz clock. I am using an STM32F7 microcontroller. On those parts, the 32kHz crystal oscillator requires up to 5 seconds to start. I like your idea of letting the BNO055 start up using the internal oscillator, then switching the BNO055 to the external 32kHz clock only after the STM32F7 32kHz oscillator is stable.

Answer (score 1):

Only the datasheet can tell you this for sure.  Since you didn't provide a link, we can't tell you directly if this would work.

However, in most cases, crystal driver inputs are high impedance with a threshold near the middle.  Driving it with a full amplitude square wave *should* work.  Most of the time.  Probably.

Again, **read the datasheet**.

### Reading the datasheet

Now that you have supplied a link to the datasheet, we can see that, as expected, it directly answers your question.

On page 17, section 2, *Absolute Maximum Ratings*, Table 2-1, it shows:

[image]

This clearly shows that any non-supply pin is fine as long as it doesn't exceed the GND to V<sub>DDIO</sub> range by 300 mV at each end.  V<sub>DDIO</sub> is the supply voltage for the logic section, so obviously GND to V<sub>DDIO</sub> won't hurt any digital input.

In addition, in section 5.1 *Pin-out*, page 97, Table 5-1 *Pin description*, it makes it clear that the crystal input is considered a digital input:

[image]

While the XIN32 input probably stays near the middle of its voltage range when using a crystal (as described in detail on page 101), it is completely clear that driving it from 0 to V<sub>DDIO</sub> will cause no harm.

Again, you have to actually **read** the datasheet.  Just skimming is not good enough, although in this case it was easy to find the relevant sections quickly.  Finding the information took me less time than copying and pasting snippets into this answer and writing the text around them.

Comment: Here is the [Datasheet](https://ae-bst.resource.bosch.com/media/_tech/media/datasheets/BST_BNO055_DS000_14.pdf), which of course I've read. I could not find the information, but I may have missed something, or may not know what I'm looking for. As mentioned in my comment above, I thought there would be a generalizable answer to my question, but apparently I'm wrong.

Comment: There is a general answer and mine is correct.  Olin's uncertainty is not based on design but perhaps uncertainty of the user error like putting 5V logic into a 3.3V chip.  You can assume the input impedance is > 1M and typical CMOS input capacitance for that device.

Comment: @Olin. I did read that, but did not know to consider the input from a Xtal to be a "logic pin", though in retrospect "digital in" I could have assumed to mean the same. I also did not know if there were any other special considerations that were not detailed in the datasheet, but that with knowledge of the typical internal implementation would be clear. I have also been bitten by incorrect/sloppy datasheets before. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Reading datasheets is always a good idea. To expand on some concerns about driving full CMOS33 level on XTAL-INs, there could be some caveats. In the quest to save power and device sizes, crystals are getting smaller and smaller. And they require less and less drive power (microwatts) for not to be "overdriven". Which means low voltages. Which means low-voltage transistors/gates. As result, designers employ low-voltage circuits locally, and might have some limitations on input thresholds/levels. I know of one design where overvoltage on XIN could cause severe lifetime degradation, at least theoretically, while it worked in short test runs. So, follow Olin's advice and read the datasheet.

Comment: (See also my comment on Olin's answer.) I was thinking of putting a high-ish (10k or 33k) resister in line with the connection to prevent over-current if I hit the end-stops on an input not meant for full range voltage. Do you think that would be enough to prevent long-term damage, in absense of further information?

Comment: @CaptainNormal, from the datasheet, they clearly designate an option for XIN32 as "optional OSC input", and the pinout table says "Digital IN". So you should be fine without any limiters.

Answer (score 0):

The Xtal IN is the same as any other CMOS logic inverter input.  So yes you can and may use a compatible voltage external clock.

Comment: The subsequent answers seem to disagree with this. But you speak with a certain authority... Do you think they are wrong to think that it highly depends upon the chip whose XTAL-IN is being driven?

Comment: There is no contradiction.  The inverter is just self-bias with 1~10M and the Xtalout is always the input inverted.  There may be a transmission gate internal for the internal clock when enabled.  This is how all Xtal Oscillators are designed in CMOS. So  normal input logic levels apply. When a resonator or xtal is used the input sees a self-biased sine wave and the inverter has sufficient analog gain to convert to a square wave with 50% duty cycle.  The ESD protection diodes prevent any possible xtal gain with its high impedance from excess voltage,

Comment: @CaptainNormal: "*The subsequent answers ...*" doesn't make much sense on StackExchange. The default sort order is by votes so answers usually don't show up in date order.

Comment: I thought it was heuristic based on last edits. In any case my answer defines the general case and all cases unless someone knows of an exception I have yet to see.  at least this chip is done this way.