# Drive XTAL lines with a external GPIO or wave gnerator

Tags: oscillator, gpio

I would like to ask a question regarding the possibility to use a GPIO from an external MCU or evern a wave generator instead of a XTAL in ICs.
I've found this post ([Drive XTAL input with logic signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340229/drive-xtal-input-with-logic-signal)), where someone asked similar question, but for a specific device, and I'm not sure if that can be extended to any other.
As reading the datasheet in some cases is marked as "digital input" some others are marked as "analog input".
I think the internal circuitry is not prepared for a digital I/O to be connected there, unless you configure it as GPIO pins if the IC has that capability, but if you declare that pin as XTAL pins, I'm not sure if driving it with external GPIO or wave generator will work, as the internal circuitry should be expecting a passive component outside, am I right?
Could the device be damaged if I use an external signal to drive the XTAL? In that case, I guess I should connect it to the XTAL IN and connect XTAL OUT to GND? or maybe leave floating?

Comment: *XTAL OUT to GND? or maybe leave floating?* ...leave it floating while you drive the *XTAL IN* pin. Just be sure you've properly identified *XTAL-IN* versus *XTAL-OUT*. If you have an option to disable the crystal oscillator function in favour of an external clock source - that would likely be a better choice. A better answer might be offered if you identified a specific chip.

Comment: Should be possible and it is possible, but not all MCUs support this so the general answer is yes it is definitelu possible but depending on what MCU you have it might not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Most ICs have the option of bypassing the XTAL and directly providing an external clock via XTAL_IN. However, **the procedure to enable this feature and the clock levels and timing requirements may vary from one MCU to another**.

For eg., in ATmega328P, to enable external clock input, some fuses need to be programmed  (datasheet@ http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf). From this datasheet, I see the following are the levels and timing requirements. So, the GPIO that drives this needs to meet these requirements.

[image]

[image]

While driving XTAL_IN, XTAL_OUT should not be grounded.

Answer (score 0):

> *I would like to ask a question regarding the possibility to use a GPIO
> from an external MCU or even a wave generator instead of a XTAL in ICs*

In most cases you can usually drive an XTAL_IN pin with an external oscillator source. In fact people do this when using two or more MCUs in a design. One MCU can be attached to a regular crystal and, the XTAL_OUT pin on that MCU can be used to drive other MCUs that share the same power rail. You can even buy oscillator modules that can drive a clock input into an XTAL_IN pin.

> *I'm not sure if driving it with external GPIO or wave generator will
> work, as the internal circuitry should be expecting a passive
> component outside, am I right?*

An XTAL_IN can accept a digital waveform and it doesn't know or care about external analogue components.

> *Could the device be damaged if I use an external signal to drive the
> XTAL?*

Well, it's impossible to say that it will be good for all devices both now and in the future so, it comes down to reading the data sheet and making sure you don't exceed maximum ratings but, it never hurts to put a 100 Ω resistor in series with the input just as an added protection or, for peace of mind.